# Modify and add new records to an Access database

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, mod-rewrite, vba

We have a MS Access 2016 database. We queried the DB to find some parts in inventory. The first few rows of the query results are below. We have a primary key called DBID with a unique number for all of our records in the original table.

ORIGINAL QUERY:

```
SELECT [Slash Series Query].BRAND, [Slash Series Query].[PRODUCT ID], [Slash Series Query].[STOCK QUANTITY] FROM [Slash Series Query] WHERE ((([Slash Series Query].[PRODUCT ID]) Not Like "k"));
```

RESULTS:

```
Slash Straight Bore Query

BRAND PRODUCT ID
FAG 230/500 BMB H14C W33
SKF 230/500 CA C08 W509
ZKL 230/500 MW33
KOY 230/500 RW513 SOFY
KOY 230/500R W33 C3 FY
FAG 230/530 MBR50150H78CW209C
FAG 230/530 C3 H40AC
NSK 230/530CAM E4 C3 S11
FAG 230/600 BM C3 W33 T52BW
FAG 230/600 C08W503
SKF 230/600 CA C08 W509
FAG 239/530 MBH40.T52BW
FAG 239/530MB
SKF 248/530 CAMA/C3/W20
TOR 249/850 W33 W45 CW57 C2
```

We would like to insert a solution that adds a new record to the database with a “K” in the part number and also adds a “_(MOD)” to the end of the part number, in addition to the existing part number, so it would look like this:

(Brand = 3 letter manufacturer code, Product ID = part number)

```
Slash Tapered Bore Query

BRAND PRODUCT ID
FAG 230/500 K BMB H14C W33 (MOD)
SKF 230/500 K CA C08 W509 (MOD)
ZKL 230/500 K MW33 (MOD)
KOY 230/500 K RW513 SOFY (MOD)
KOY 230/500 K R W33 C3 FY (MOD)
FAG 230/530 K MBR50150H78CW209C (MOD)
FAG 230/530 K C3 H40AC (MOD)
NSK 230/530 K CAM E4 C3 S11 (MOD)
FAG 230/600 K BM C3 W33 T52BW (MOD)
FAG 230/600 K C08W503 (MOD)
SKF 230/600 K CA C08 W509 (MOD)
FAG 239/530 K MBH40.T52BW (MOD)
FAG 239/530 K MB (MOD)
SKF 248/530 K CAMA/C3/W20 (MOD)
TOR 249/850 K W33 W45 CW57 C2 (MOD)
```

What would be the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you add your existing query to your question?

Comment: SELECT [Slash Series Query].BRAND, [Slash Series Query].[PRODUCT ID], [Slash Series Query].[STOCK QUANTITY]
FROM [Slash Series Query]
WHERE ((([Slash Series Query].[PRODUCT ID]) Not Like "*k*"));

Comment: The original query to the master table: SELECT [Slash Series Query].BRAND, [Slash Series Query].[PRODUCT ID], [Slash Series Query].[STOCK QUANTITY]
FROM [Slash Series Query]
WHERE ((([Slash Series Query].[PRODUCT ID]) Not Like "*k*"));

Comment: So you want a ' K' inserted after the 6th character of the product Id and a ` MOD` added after it?

Comment: Yes. that would be awesome for this data set.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the MS Access substring and concatenation operators:

```
SELECT S.BRAND, 
Mid(S.[PRODUCT ID], 1, 7) & " K" & Mid(S.[PRODUCT ID], 8) & " (MOD)" as [PRODUCT ID], 
S.[STOCK QUANTITY] 
FROM [Slash Series Query] S WHERE (S.[PRODUCT ID] Not Like "k");
```

I've used the table alias instead of the whole table name to reduce the query's size.

EXPLANATION:

```
Mid(columnName, starting char position, [optional last character position])
```

returns that part of the column value from the starting char position to the last character position if specified(end of the string if not specified.)

`"a" & "b" & "c"` uses the MS access concatenation operator `&` and results in `"abc"`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to select the values:

```
SELECT ssq.BRAND, ssq.[PRODUCT ID], ssq.[STOCK QUANTITY],
       ("K" & ssq.[PART NUMBER] & " (MOD)") as [PRODUCT ID]
FROM [Slash Series Query] as ss1q
WHERE ssq.[PRODUCT ID] Not Like "k";
```

If you want to insert this into the database, then use `INSERT . . . SELECT`.

Comment: I don't think there's a separate "PART number" column